# how to recover my installation after accidental removal of important packages

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu

I used muon to remove packages handling usb devices, on uninstallation I just clicked ok on removal of other dependend packes. after a restart my kubuntu started only partially. there is a gui login, but after entering name and pwd it stalls. (no icons for loading modules)

I can access the command line login, but essential parts seems missing:
I can sudo, but there is no longer an apt-get command. So I can not reinstall any packages.

Even if I boot older kernels they seem to be broken.

If I call apt-get with any parameter I get the error `command not found`. `which apt-get` returns nothing and I can't find an apt-get command.

what can be done to revive the installation?

Comment: It is probably easiest to reinstall and reload from your backups.

Answer (score 0):

Most stable way (and fastest in this situation) is to make a **clean install**, so make a new ubuntu live USB.

**If you have a dedicated partition for `/home`**, launch the installer. In disk and partitions setup, choose 'other' and manually select the partition for `/` and `/home`. Eensure that the installer will format `/` partition only.

**If you have one partition only**, launch live USB choosing **try ubuntu**. On desktop, open file manager and navigate to your `/home` directory. Display hidden files, press `Ctrl+A` and copy everything to another USB (or you can just use Gparted to shrink your current partition and create a new one for `/home`).